# jQuery position() top is different in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, css

When I run the following fiddle in Chrome and Opera, the position().top is returned as 0, but Firefox is returning 1 and IE return 0.5.

How can I fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/scottieslg/Loefza24/2/

Html:

```
<table id='testTable'>
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id='topPos'></div>
```

css:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#testTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#testTable thead tr td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var topPos = $("#testTable thead tr:nth-child(1)").position().top;
    console.log(topPos);
    $("#topPos").html("Top: " + topPos);
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to fix it?

Comment: Because I'm absolutely positioning some elements in the page over table, and they are displaying differently in Firefox.

Comment: Use [offset().top](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: @MaxZoom: `offset()` is giving the same numbers.

Comment: @Scottie can you create an offset variable that accounts for the change? Something you can set before the positioning is done that you factor into the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like FF just doesn't consider the border to be a part of the element. As a possible solution you can use   box-shadow instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var topPos = $("#testTable thead tr:nth-child(1)").position().top;
    console.log(topPos);
    $("#topPos").html("Top: " + topPos);
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#testTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#testTable thead tr td {
     box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 1px #ccc inset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='testTable'>
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Body</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id='topPos'></div>
```